# Is it possible to have preference Index < 0

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying set summary for sharedPreference of listPreference, it occur to me that it is necessary to check (prefIndex >= 0) but why, is it possible to have index below zero if so in which condition?

```
private void setPreferenceSummary(Preference preference, String value) {

if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {

    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(value);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            // Set the summary to that label
            listPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read `ListPreference#findIndexOfValue` javadocs?

Comment: @pskink not at first but after you mention I did but it basically returning the array index which can be null but not below zero so why can't we check for null instead checking for negative values? And read it from Android docs.

Comment: no, it cannot be null, `findIndexOfValue` returns `int` value - so it cannot be null

Comment: @pskink you are right, finally read out everything in that doc, at first it did confused me though, thank you :)

Comment: sure, your welcome